# Microsoft Excel: Extending the x-axis of a chart without disturbing existing vertical gridlines

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 50 rows on my chart for the X-axis. Now I need to add 10 more rows. If I right click on the chart & click on "Select data" & then increase the Chart Data Range by 10 more rows, then Excel keeps the overall size of my chart the same & adds the 10 more rows. I have existing labels, lines & other stuff I draw on top of my char. All of these get displaced. How do I make Excel increase the horizontal length of the chart while adding more rows. This will keep the existing points at their current location while adding space on the right hand side.

[image]

If you see in the pic above, adding 5 extra rows has kept the chart size the same while compressing the extra rows in the same space. So my label on Day 6 now points to Day 9. What I want is that the x axis be made longer while adding new rows.

I am using Excel 2016, Home & Student Edition

Answer (score 3):

A more robust approach would be not to add text boxes and arrows and other shapes, but instead add a data label to the particular point, format it, and make sure leader lines are showing. Adding data to the chart will move data within the chart, but the data label will keep its association with its data point.

To add a single data label, click once to select the series, click again to select the point, right click and choose Add Data Label. Drag it and format it like any shape.

[image]

Comment: That would work for the Text Labels, but what about lines & other stuff I draw on the chart. Is there now way to just add the additional rows to the right of the current rows without compressing the existing chart?

Comment: What lines are you adding? My leader lines move with the points and data labels. For other lines, well, a line is defined by two points. Add these two points to the chart as an XY scatter series, on the primary axis. As the axes changes, the line's endpoints stay fixed with respect to the axes.

Comment: I know you were asking how to stretch the chart to accommodate more columns, without affecting the lines and textboxes in the chart, but that's not easy to do. It's a lot of algebra to keep track of, and the shapes move and distort as they please. So you would have to reposition and reshape all of the shapes even if you did somehow make the chart stretch uniformly.

Comment: My chart is actually a Stock/Candlestick chart. Excel does not allow Combo charts with Stock charts - so I wouldn't be able to add a scatter series

Comment: I don't think it would be a lot of algebra - opposite actually - fitting more elements in existing space would be a lot of algebra because every element will move. OTOH, if you add all the extra rows to the right, then the existing elements wouldn't move at all, so no algebra

Answer (score 1):

To draw lines that move with the axes, plot them as XY scatter series.

Suppose I want to put a box around a few of the columns. I've added some data with the corners of the box. The X values are 1.5 (midway between categories 1 and 2) and 4.5 (midway between categories 4 and 5). The Y values are at 0 (along the X axis) and 5.5 (just above the tallest enclosed bar). The central point at X=3 is for adding a data label to describe the box.

Copy these data values, including the first row of labels. Select the chart, and use Paste Special to add the data as a new series, and using the other options as shown.

[image: Copy Data -> Paste Special as New Series]

The data is added as another set of columns. Right click either series, and choose Change Series Chart Type. Change the new series to an XY Scatter with Lines (and no markers), and uncheck the Secondary Axis box. And look how nicely the box aligns with the columns.

[image: Change Series Chart Type]

I've added a data label above the central point mentioned earlier, and formatted the text color to match the lines of the box. When the series of columns is extended, the axes change, but the box keeps its relative position with the columns.

[image: The lines and labels move with the axes]

Comment: I wish to do this with a Stock/Candlestick chart - Combo charts aren't allowed with Stock charts.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens to shapes embedded in a chart when we extend the chart's axis and stretch the chart. At the top is a stock chart created with the gold-shaded data, with two shapes. Below that is the same chart, with the data range extended to include the blue shaded data, and the chart stretched so that the pre-existing data takes up about the same amount of space. The stretch isn't not exact, but it's good enough to show that the shapes also move and stretch, so the premise that stretching the chart will keep the shapes aligned with the same points is flawed.

[image: Stretch a chart containing shapes, and the shapes also move and stretch.]

Another flawed premise is that a stock chart cannot be combined with another chart type. Here is the same stock chart, and I want to draw a box around the candlesticks that show increasing values.

[image: Original stock chart]

The data I will use for the box (using an XY Scatter type) is shown below. The X values in the first column were defined based on the category numbers in the first column above (the category numbers are not used in the chart).

I've copied the blue shaded range, selected the chart, and used Paste Special as in my other answer to add the series to the chart (top right below). So far so good.

If you right click on any series or on the chart, and choose Change (Series) Chart Type, you are told that you can't combine chart types blah blah. Go ahead and click the button the change the chart anyway. In the dialog that pops up, choose Combo in the list on the left, then in the list of series on the right, make sure all of the first four are type Line, and the last one is XY Scatter (I used markers in the scatter series so you can see the points). The chart (bottom left) has lines connecting points in the open, high, low, and close series, but it retains the up-down bars and the high-low lines. And the box is aligned right where we want it.

Finally, clean up the chart. Format O, H, L, and C to use no lines. Also, I added a data label to the point at the midpoint of the bottom of the box, and used the series name as the label text. Probably should get rid of the legend, too.

[image: Pseudo-Stock combo chart]

If I extend the data by another week, the box stays aligned to its original points, because the coordinates of the box are tied to the axes of the chart. I can stretch the chart if I want, and the box stays aligned.

[image: The XY scatter box stays perfectly aligned however much I extend the chart data or stretch the chart]